# What does "If you are playing the Yankees, you don’t want the umpires to show up wearing pinstripes" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

The sentence goes:

> A good judge, like a good umpire, cannot act as a partisan... If you are playing the Yankees, you don’t want the umpires to show up wearing pinstripes.

I cannot understand the part after the ellipsis. "Show up wearing pinstripes" seems to be a proverb or slang. Could anyone help explain?

Comment: The Yankees’ uniform is striped.Image from http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/photo/photogallery/springtraining_2004/0329j/01.jpg

Comment: There is nothing in the *language* used in this quotation that needs an explanation; what the question calls for is an explanation of certain facts about baseball.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an illustration of the rule expressed in the preceding sentence. If you want to be (or appear) impartial, do not wear the uniform of one of the teams.

> The [Yankees] home uniform is white with distinctive pinstripes and a
>   navy interlocking "NY" at the chest.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos_and_uniforms_of_the_New_York_Yankees#Design_and_appearance_of_uniform)

Answer (score 16):

In American Major League Baseball, the New York Yankees traditionally wear pinstripes on their uniforms.

https://ftw.usatoday.com/2013/04/yankees-pinstripes-origin-babe-ruth [1](https://ftw.usatoday.com/2013/04/yankees-pinstripes-origin-babe-ruth)

Thus, for the umpires, who are supposed to be impartial judges, to "show up wearing pinstripes," would suggest they were, in fact, favoring the Yankees.